# monthly payment and single payment in the same place

Tags: gui-design, interface, payment

Good morning, I'm doing a payment area, where the user can buy a monthly product and a single purchase product, the project owner demands that the payment be the same for both forms, it can be on credit card or Bank slip. But it does not make sense to pay a product that is paid every month in installments with a single purchase. Would anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What are your concerns?

Comment: If someone bought the two modes and split the purchase it would be incorrect in my vision. why would I pay a monthly bill in 4 times and the other months ahead how would this be done?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to make sense. If the first entry ($20/month) is, essentially, an on-going "subscription" to something, and the second entry ($180 on-off) is being paid-for over four months, then that doesn't equate to $50 x 4 (that only includes _one_ installment for the first product: 180+20 = 200 = 50 x 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, I think here should be a another process (with identical UI Design and logic, differing in a few variables getting from the api (in this case, the price and subscription period).

In step back you should ask the user (for example, radio button) which version of the subscription he wants to use.

[image: Proces]

[image: UI Example]

Of course this UI wireframe is only example, when you spent time on this, i'm certain You find better & easier solution.